cli ssh to remote-host through an intermediate jump-host
I need to connect to remote-hosts, through python/netmiko scripts, running on the local-host (Mac cli). Those remote-hosts are only accessible through a jump-host. I have it setup within SecureCRT where I first open up a master socks session, to the jump-host with dynamic port forwarding, and then open up connections to the remote-host. I need to do something similar but for my scripts running from the cli on local-host.
I was hoping that if I run the master session from within SecureCRT I would be able to use the dynamic port (1080) and connect to the remote-host, through the socks proxy session to the jump-host. That however did not work.
Thanks.
Abid Ghufran
